# How can i get the pane's round in the scenebuilder?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, pane

[Image from Scenebuilder project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrD96.png)

I want to make this panes round.
I can not do it with border radius because i need to check the background-color of the pane in my java code. How can i get the pane's round?

Comment: I am not sure why you can't use the border-radius? How does needing to check the background-color limit you from changing the border-radius?

Comment: Post your `FXML`.